# Regex Match all characters between two strings in documents

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this text that I want to capture

> **Title**       : CRB: Genetic Diversity of Endangered Populations of
>   Mysticete Whales:
>                  Mitochondrial DNA and Historical Demography Type        : Award NSF Org     : DEB  Latest Amendment Date        : August 1, 
>   1991      File        : a9000006
>
> Award Number: 9000006 Award Instr.: Continuing grant
>   Prgm Manager: Scott Collins
>           DEB  DIVISION OF ENVIRONMENTAL BIOLOGY
>           BIO  DIRECT FOR BIOLOGICAL SCIENCES           Start Date  : June 1,  1990        Expires     : November 30,  1992   (Estimated)
>   Expected Total Amt.  : $179720             (Estimated) Investigator:
>   Stephen R. Palumbi   (Principal Investigator current) Sponsor     : U
>   of Hawaii Manoa
>           2530 Dole Street
>           Honolulu, HI  968222225    808/956-7800
>
> NSF Program : 1127      SYSTEMATIC & POPULATION BIOLO Fld Applictn:
>   0000099   Other Applications NEC
>                 61        Life Science Biological                  Program Ref : 9285, **Abstract**    :
>
> ```
>           Commercial exploitation over the past two hundred years drove                  
>           the great Mysticete whales to near extinction.  Variation in                   
>           the sizes of populations prior to exploitation, minimal                        
>           population size during exploitation and current population                     
>           sizes permit analyses of the effects of differing levels of                    
>           exploitation on species with different biogeographical                         
>           distributions and life-history characteristics.  Dr. Stephen                   
>           Palumbi at the University of Hawaii will study the genetic                     
>           population structure of three whale species in this context,                   
>           the Humpback Whale, the Gray Whale and the Bowhead Whale.  The                 
>           effect of demographic history will be determined by comparing                  
>           the genetic structure of the three species.  Additional studies                
>           will be carried out on the Humpback Whale.  The humpback has a                 
>           world-wide distribution, but the Atlantic and Pacific                          
>           populations of the northern hemisphere appear to be discrete                   
>           populations, as is the population of the southern hemispheric                  
>           oceans.  Each of these oceanic populations may be further                      
>           subdivided into smaller isolates, each with its own migratory                  
>           pattern and somewhat distinct gene pool.  This study will                      
>           provide information on the level of genetic isolation among                    
>           populations and the levels of gene flow and genealogical                       
>           relationships among populations.  This detailed genetic                        
>           information will facilitate international policy decisions                     
>           regarding the conservation and management of these magnificent                 
>           mammals.
> ```

I want to match every character between "**Title**" and "**Abstract**". I have try **(?<=Title)(.*)(?=Asbtract)*** and **\bTitle\b(.?)\bAbstract\b**, but didn't work. I can't figure out, what the correct syntax.

Comment: Actually, you need to specify your language. So, the regex will become very clear.

Comment: This is for java, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\\bTitle\\b([\\s\\S]*?)\\bAbstract\\b
```

`.` does not match `newlines` by default.So use `s` flag or `[\s\S]`

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/lR1eC9/6

Comment: Side note: a backslash needs to be escaped by another backslash, since Java handles regexps through string literals, where backslashes already have a special meaning (used to escape). The actual produced regex then is: `\bTitle\b([\s\S]*?)\bAbstract\b`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following regex:

```
Title\s*\:(.*?)Abstract\s*\:
```